# Custom starter workflows github not showing up in organization

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-organizations

We created a public .github repository in our organization in order to create custom starter workflows as per:

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/using-workflows/creating-starter-workflows-for-your-organization

but can't seem to see them when creating a new repo.

[image: Query starter workflow]

Here is our github repo https://github.com/pepsico-ecommerce/.github

Comment: I believe the path is `workflow-templates` in the `.github` repo, and not `.github/workflow-templates`.

Answer (score 2):

> but can't seem to see them when creating a new repo.

Check if the new repository created is a public or private one, and test it for a user (outside an organization).

The documentation does mention:

> Starter workflows created by users can only be used to create workflows in public repositories.
>
> Organizations using GitHub Enterprise Cloud can also use starter workflows to create workflows in private repositories.

Your use-case seems to match the first scenario, since you are not using [GitHub Enterprise Cloud](https://github.com/enterprise).
Meaning a `.github/workflow-templates` would not work on `github.com`.
It would on a GitHub Enterprise Cloud instance.

Comment: I am using github enterprise, could you expand your answer to address this case also?

Comment: @Mathew Right,  GitHub Enterprise Cloud is hosted by GitHub, I forgot. The documentation mentions: "These can then be used by organization members who have permission to create workflows.": does your new repository (with the missing stater workflow) was created by a member of the organization wit the right to create workflow?

Comment: Making repository public worked for me. Thanks.